# How to average last amount of last 5 transactions

Tags: mysql, limit

I have two transaction table and a product table.  The product table has a column called "product".  The transaction table has a column called "amount".  I want to get the average of the last 5 transaction for each product.  I have this so far, but can't figure out a statement to make it grab the only the last 5 of each distinct product:

```
SELECT avg(amount) as price, p.product_name, p.producer
FROM wp_transactions t
JOIN wp_products p
ON t.product_ID = p.ID
WHERE t.status = 'approved'
GROUP BY p.product_name
ORDER BY p.producer ASC, p.product_name ASC;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by enumerating the rows usig variables:

```
SELECT avg(amount) as price, p.product_name, p.producer
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             (@rn := if(@p = t.Product_Id, @rn + 1,
                        if(@pr := t.Product_Id, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as seqnum
      FROM wp_transactions t CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT @rn := 0, @p := 0) vars
      WHERE t.status = 'approved'
      ORDER BY t.product_ID, t.datetime
     ) t JOIN
     wp_products p
     ON t.product_ID = p.ID
WHERE seqnum <= 5
GROUP BY p.product_name
ORDER BY p.producer ASC, p.product_name ASC;
```

Comment: Out of curiosity - wouldn't it be easier to optimize if it was `HAVING seqnum <= 5` in the inner query?

Comment: @zerkms . . . I suppose in MySQL that would reduce the size of the materialized subquery, so it would be a bit more efficient.  However, I'm not sure how the `having` clause interacts with the `group by` and hence the variables, so I'm not sure if that would really work.

Comment: `HAVING` node is applied after `GROUP BY`, so for the `GROUP BY` it "does not exist". So the potential win in using it is that if optimizer is not smart enough to push predicates from outer queries (or vice versa) then at least to reduce the result set (the size of the materialized subquery).